# Razorpay API gives inavlid key error even though the key is valid

Tags: javascript, python, api, payment, razorpay

Have been working on Razorpay payments API using flask,facing this issue since forever

```
    import razorpay
    import json

    from flask import Flask, render_template, request ,jsonify

    app = Flask(__name__)
    razorpay_client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_8ydfJQKGSKoloz", "7LNONq8PYWjg4ImLujHDxpst"))

    order_id = ''

    def app_create():
        order_amount = 50000
        order_currency = 'INR'
        order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_100'
        notes = {'Shipping address': 'Pune, Maharashtra'}
        something = razorpay_client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency,                         receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes))
return something['id']

    @app.route('/')
    def app_start() :
        return render_template('app.html')

    #@app.route('/create')
    #def app_create():
       # order_amount = 50000
       # order_currency = 'INR'
       # order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_100'
      #  notes = {'Shipping address': 'Pune, Maharashtra'}
      #  something = razorpay_client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency,         receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes))
      #  order_id = something['id']
      #  return(something)


    @app.route('/pay')
    def app_pay():

        order_id = app_create()

        razrp_config = {
            "options" : {
                            "key": "7LNONq8PYWjg4ImLujHDxpst",
                            "amount": "50000",
                            "currency": "INR",
                            "name": "Acme Corp",
                            "description": "Test Transaction",
                            "order_id": order_id,
                            "callback_url": "https://eneqd3r9zrjok.x.pipedream.net/",
                            "notes": {
                                        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
                                    },
                            "theme": {
                                    "color": "#3399cc"
                                } 
                    }        
}
        return jsonify(razrp_config)


    @app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
    def app_charge():
        amount = 50000
        payment_id = request.form['razorpay_payment_id']
        razorpay_client.payment.capture(payment_id, amount)
        return json.dumps(razorpay_client.payment.fetch(payment_id))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

that was the python code, the javscript :

```
   // Get data 
   //fetch('/create')
   //.then((result) => { console.log( result.json() )})


   fetch('/pay')
   .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
   .then((data) => {
     // Initialize js
     console.log(data)
     const rzp1 = new Razorpay(data.options);
     // Event handler
     document.querySelector("#submitBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
       rzp1.open()
       //fetch('/charge')
       //.then((result) => { return result.json(); })
       //.then((data) => {
       //  console.log(data);
         // Redirect 
       //})
     });
   });
```

there are a lot of comments, try to look past them, when i click the button on the html dom it gives an error : 'serviceworker' should be a dict in the web app manifest

I get the API key is invalid error when infact it is valid and recent

Comment: Here is the html code   `
          
<div class="container">
        <button class="button is-primary" id="submitBtn">Purchase!</button>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  `

Comment: Please, edit your question to include all relevant information, incl. the full traceback. Don't add info in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you are passing in options is invalid.

use correct keys. try using the keys you mentioned at the top.

> "options" : {
> "key": "rzp_test_8ydfJQKGSKoloz"